# Android ViewFlipper with ImageViews crashes from too much memory usage

Tags: android, image, memory-management

I have a ViewFlipper loaded with ImageViews (about 24) which are screenshots for the app, as a user guide. The user would bring up this activity, and flip through the images to see how the app works.

Unfortunately, it's crashing on phones and emulators due to too much memory from loading up all of the images(my first design was tested on a nook Color running Honeycomb) running 2.2 and 2.3 (which I am required to support).

Can you suggest a code design alternative to limit the amount of memory required? Loading a few images at once, nulling images, alternative compression or format, etc?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a `Gallery` or `ViewPager` with a `PagerAdapter`(new! included in compatibility package).  the `PagerAdapter` will destroy/create each page when it needs to.  You can re-use views using a `Gallery` in a custom adapter.

see http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html

Answer (score 0):

Rather than loading all the images at once, perhaps try something like a ViewSwitcher, with two child ImageViews. Keep a reference to what position you're in for the list of screenshots, and each time the view is switched, determine in which direction it is being switched (previous or next), and change the image of the next ImageView prior to switching. That way, you should only have one or two images in memory at any time.

EDIT: binnyb's idea sounds better to me. :)